# Get rid of apt update warnings

Tags: apt

I had a 21.04 system that gave no warnings when I ran apt update, but then I ran this command (suggested by the internet)

```
add-apt-repository universe
```

and after that I get warnings when running

```
apt update
```

The warnings are

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-sv' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-sv_SE' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Here is the content of my /etc/apt/sources.list

```
# deb cdrom:[Ubuntu 20.04 LTS _Focal Fossa_ - Release amd64 (20200423)]/ focal main restricted

# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute universe
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal universe
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates universe
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute multiverse
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal multiverse
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://se.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ focal-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner universe
# deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu focal partner

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

EDIT: Added /etc/apt/sources.list and tried to clarify what I did to mess up my system.

Comment: It looks like your sources are messed up.   Edit your question and post the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`  .  In your edit you should also provide more context about your activities since the last time you successfully performed updates.  In particular, share the details of alterations you made to your sources.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You created the problem when you created the line that says

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner universe
```

Edit that line to the following, which will stop the errors:

```
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner
```