# Why does Discover show a message about universe when it starts?

Tags: apt, package-management, kubuntu, dpkg, discover-software-center

The following appears briefly when I start the Discover app. I had to take a picture and copy it by hand. I believe it has something to do with dpkg because I have seen similar messages before with dpkg mentioned. What can I do to fix this? At the bottom I left some info about my system.

```
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/source/Sources' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe'(component misspeltin sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'universe/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http:..archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute InRelease' doesn't have the component 'universe' (component misspelt in sources.list?)...


Linux Haswell 5.11.0-25-generic #27-Ubuntu SMP
Kubuntu
Ubuntu 21.04 hirsute
KDE Plasma version: 5.21.4
Intel Haswell i7 CPU, 16GB RAM
```

Here are the contents of `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```bsh
# deb cdrom:[Kubuntu 21.04 _Hirsute Hippo_ - Release amd64 (20210420)]/ hirsute main multiverse restricted universe
# deb http://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/debian buster-cran40/ universe
# See http://help.ubuntu.com/community/UpgradeNotes for how to upgrade to
# newer versions of the distribution.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted
# deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute main restricted

## Major bug fix updates produced after the final release of the
## distribution.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted
# deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates main restricted

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu
## team. Also, please note that software in universe WILL NOT receive any
## review or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute universe
# deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute universe
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates universe
# deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates universe

## N.B. software from this repository is ENTIRELY UNSUPPORTED by the Ubuntu 
## team, and may not be under a free licence. Please satisfy yourself as to 
## your rights to use the software. Also, please note that software in 
## multiverse WILL NOT receive any review or updates from the Ubuntu
## security team.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute multiverse
# deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute multiverse
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates multiverse
# deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-updates multiverse

## N.B. software from this repository may not have been tested as
## extensively as that contained in the main release, although it includes
## newer versions of some applications which may provide useful features.
## Also, please note that software in backports WILL NOT receive any review
## or updates from the Ubuntu security team.
deb http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse
# deb-src http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ hirsute-backports main restricted universe multiverse

## Uncomment the following two lines to add software from Canonical's
## 'partner' repository.
## This software is not part of Ubuntu, but is offered by Canonical and the
## respective vendors as a service to Ubuntu users.
deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner universe
deb-src http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu hirsute partner universe

deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security main restricted
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security main restricted
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security universe
deb http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security multiverse
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu hirsute-security multiverse

# This system was installed using small removable media
# (e.g. netinst, live or single CD). The matching "deb cdrom"
# entries were disabled at the end of the installation process.
# For information about how to configure apt package sources,
# see the sources.list(5) manual.
```

Comment: The error is telling you that there is a problem with your sources. Please edit your question with the output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`. When editing please format your post appropriately. [Use code fences](https://askubuntu.com/editing-help#) for terminal commands and output so that we can parse the information correctly.  Code fences have three backticks on the line before and three backticks on the line after code blocks.

Comment: Thanks. I did as you suggested. I tried to find out why the added text came in such a huge font but could not figure it out. I put the text between two rows of three backticks.

Comment: The reason it wasn't formatted properly was because there was another code block from a previous edit.  You need to "open" and "close" each code block with three backticks.  I believe the problem might be that the two lines that end with `partner universe` are incorrect.  Make a backup of this file: `sudo cp /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.bak`. If you need the `partner` repo, remove the `universe` from these two lines. If you don't need `partner`, put a `#` in front of those two lines to comment them out.  Run `sudo apt update` to see if there is still a problem and report back.

Comment: @Nmath - There was progress. The only suspicious lines after doing _sudo apt update_ were:
_E: The repository 'http://ppa.launchpad.net/teejee2008/ppa/ubuntu hirsute Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details._

Comment: What do you use that ppa for? Is it maintained?  See [What can I do if a repository/PPA does not have a Release file?](https://askubuntu.com/q/866901)

Comment: Thanks for your patience. I started with Linux four days ago. I managed to make it work so well that now I am using much more my Linux PC than my Windows PC even though my Windows PC has a much faster CPU. But I have no idea what is ppa, so I cannot answer your question. I will do a Google search.

Comment: I'm talking about the ppa `teejee2008`. It's not very good if you don't know how it got there because that means you've been running lines in your terminal without understanding what they actually do and that you don't even remember doing it.  You would have had to manually add this ppa. I would advise as a new user not to blindly run lines in terminal unless you know what they do and how to reverse them.  PPAs are not always a "safe" way to install software.  See: https://askubuntu.com/questions/35629/are-ppas-safe-to-add-to-my-system-and-what-are-some-red-flags-to-watch-out-for

Comment: it looks like the [teejee2008 ppa](https://launchpad.net/~teejee2008/+archive/ubuntu/ppa) contains several projects, most of them are extremely out-of-date, with the last update to any project being 67 weeks ago.  Most of them are much much older. I would suggest uninstalling the associated software and [removing the ppa](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307/how-can-ppas-be-removed). Find software that's already in Ubuntu repositories, and use PPA only when absolutely necessary, and even then it should be from a source you trust and it should be up-to-date.

Comment: @Nmath - I managed to remove ```teejee2008``` and now ```sudo apt update``` has no messages suggesting problems. Thanks for your help. I will try to follow your advice on not entering commands I do not fully understand. It is hard, though. To uninstall ```teejee2008``` I had to do that: ```sudo apt-add-repository --remove ppa:teejee2008/ppa```.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get rid of apt update warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352857/get-rid-of-apt-update-warnings)