# Update error, talks of Broken package/ Missing dependencies in 21.10

Tags: apt, updates, 21.10

[image]

I am getting this error for the late 2 days. It is a red icon on the top bar which says update error, some missing dependencies (not the exact words). So I tried `sudo apt-get update` and got this output below

```
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease [270 kB]
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Get:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease [11.4 kB]           
Hit:4 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu impish InRelease   
Get:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease [110 kB]     
Get:6 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease [110 kB]    
Err:3 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                     
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_impish_InRelease into data and signature failed
Hit:7 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 Packages   
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slimbook/slimbook/ubuntu impish InRelease       
Hit:9 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main i386 Packages    
Hit:10 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main Translation-en
Hit:11 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Hit:12 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Hit:13 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Hit:14 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Hit:15 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/main amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Hit:16 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/restricted amd64 Packages
Hit:17 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/restricted i386 Packages
Hit:18 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/restricted Translation-en
Hit:19 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/restricted amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Hit:20 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe i386 Packages
Hit:21 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 Packages
Hit:22 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe Translation-en
Hit:23 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Hit:24 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe DEP-11 48x48 Icons
Hit:25 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Hit:26 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe DEP-11 64x64@2 Icons
Hit:27 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/universe amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Hit:28 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse i386 Packages
Hit:29 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse amd64 Packages
Hit:30 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse Translation-en
Hit:31 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates/multiverse amd64 c-n-f Metadata
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease              
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_impish-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
Hit:32 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slimbook/slimbook/ubuntu impish Release
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_impish_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/partial/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_impish-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
E: The repository 'http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease' is no longer signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
```

It would be nice if there can be any fix.

Edit 1:

```
    $ sudo apt-get update
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease [270 kB]
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                   
Hit:3 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease             
Hit:4 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease                     
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease              
Hit:6 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu impish InRelease
Ign:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slimbook/slimbook/ubuntu impish InRelease
Hit:9 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slimbook/slimbook/ubuntu impish Release
Fetched 270 kB in 2s (134 kB/s)                    
Reading package lists... Done
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/binary-amd64/Packages' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/i18n/Translation-en' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/i18n/Translation-en_IN' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/dep11/Components-amd64.yml' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/dep11/icons-48x48.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/dep11/icons-64x64.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/dep11/icons-64x64@2.tar' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
W: Skipping acquire of configured file 'partner/cnf/Commands-amd64' as repository 'http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease' doesn't have the component 'partner' (component misspelt in sources.list?)
```

Edit 2:

```
$ sudo apt-get update
[sudo] password for njan: 
Get:1 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish InRelease [270 kB]
Hit:2 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease                                                                                 
Hit:3 http://ppa.launchpad.net/kritalime/ppa/ubuntu impish InRelease                                                                              
Hit:4 http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-updates InRelease                                                               
Hit:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease                                                                                           
Hit:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease          
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/obsproject/obs-studio/ubuntu impish InRelease
Get:8 http://ppa.launchpad.net/slimbook/slimbook/ubuntu impish InRelease [18.1 kB]
Err:5 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_impish-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
Err:6 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease
  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_impish_InRelease into data and signature failed
Fetched 288 kB in 2s (172 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu impish-security InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_impish-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish InRelease: Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_impish_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu/dists/impish/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/archive.canonical.com_ubuntu_dists_impish_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/impish-security/InRelease  Splitting up /var/lib/apt/lists/security.ubuntu.com_ubuntu_dists_impish-security_InRelease into data and signature failed
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*´  and try again `sudo apt update`

Comment: Sorry. It is not possible to edit /etc/resolv.conf in Ubuntu Working option: Advanced Network Configuration - Network Connections - IPv4 Settings - Method:Automatic(DHCP)addresses only - DNS servers: 8.8.8.8, 8.8.4.4

Comment: @nobody thanks. Please check Edit 1 on the original post. T

Comment: ok @JohanPalych

Comment: Oh `grep -r deb /etc/apt/sources.list /etc/apt/sources.list.d`  the partner repository is wrong set some how.  It should be only in your sources as `deb http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu impish partner` be present. Please check this.

Comment: Thanks @nobody but there is still something wrong. Can you please check `Edit 2`?. I used the command you gave.

Comment: Have you a slow internet connection?  `sudo sed -i s,//in.archive,//archive,g  /etc/apt/sources.list`  This will change to main server  `sudo rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` if this is also not working I'am out of ideas.

Comment: @nobody no errors this time. Thanks :)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to resolve Skipping acquire of configured file Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1121069/how-to-resolve-skipping-acquire-of-configured-file-ubuntu-18-04-2-lts)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Get rid of apt update warnings](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1352857/get-rid-of-apt-update-warnings)